# How to override startParam and limitParam names globally in Ext js 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I am trying to change startParam and limitParam names globally by the below code.

```
Ext.define('Myapp.overrides.ProxyServer', {
  override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',
  startParam: 'page.start',
  limitParam : 'page.limit'
```

});

But still My request params name is going as start and limit as limit. Kindly help how to set them gloablly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the configs in a config block:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.overrides.ProxyServer', {
  override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',
  config: {
    startParam: 'page.start',
    limitParam : 'page.limit'
  }
});
```

Comment: The other thing to check would be that your override is running and being included.